# Adding & removing a class with vanilla Javascript - unknown side-effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add and remove a class, "on-screen", to an image wrapper div, "output-wrap" with my "outputImage" function that makes an image appear or disappear. However, when I console.log the element containing the image ("output-wrap" div) BEFORE I add the class, the console indicates the class has already been assigned! You can see from my HTML that the "output-wrap" div has no classes prior to adding the "on-screen" class. What's happening here?

Also, if the image already has the "on-screen" class, I want to remove it. But a similar phenomenon occurs. I remove the "on-screen" class via classList.remove(), but immediately after removing, a console.log of the "output-wrap" div shows the class wasn't removed. Why is this?

```js
function outputImage() {

  // Get a random image
  // let randomIndex = Math.round((Math.random() * (images.length - 1))),
  //   randomImageURL = images[randomIndex],
  const randomImageURL = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
  image = document.getElementById("output-wrap"),
    outputDiv = document.getElementById("output"),
    output = `<img src="${randomImageURL}">`;

  // If image already displayed
  if (image.classList.contains("on-screen")) {
    // Replace image
    image.classList.remove("on-screen");
    console.log(image) // Logs image with "on-screen" class...it should've been removed!
    outputDiv.innerHTML = output;

    // If no image is displayed
  } else {
    outputDiv.innerHTML = output;
    console.log(image) // Logs image with "on-screen" class before class has been added!
    image.classList.add("on-screen");
  }
}
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", outputImage);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: roboto;
  background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  color: white;
}

#output-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: -450px;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#output-wrap.on-screen {
  animation: fadeIn ease 3s;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translateX(1200px);
}

img {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="breed-wrap">
  <h1>Ultimate Dog Pic Viewer</h1>
  <label for="breed">Breed</label>
  <select name="breed" id="breed">
    <option value="" disabled selected>--Select Breed--</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btn">Show me a picture!</button>
</div>
<div id="output-wrap">
  <div id="output">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem statement is so confusing and where have you called the `outputImage` function

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as clear as possible. The outputImage function is called inside a click event function attached to the button (id="btn").

Comment: For simplicity, I've taken lorem picsum image in edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with your code. Just the `console.log` printed out the `image` at the moment AFTER adding `on-screen`. This surprised me when I just found out.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects

The correct way to do console.log in this case is

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(image, ['classList'])));
```